# Использовать содержание столбца таблицы в качестве имен таблиц для формирования запроса

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

В столбце таблицы содержатся имена других таблиц:

```
name
=======
table_1
table_pineapple
table_3
```

Нужно через цикл удалить все строки из этих таблиц:

```
delete from table_N;
```

Не понятно, как использовать поле типа `varchar2` в качестве имени для обращения к таблице.

Comment: Только динамическим SQL. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011

Comment: `execute immediate 'delete from'||table_N;`

Comment: Да, тоже сейчас занят генерацией скрипта и exec его потом. Как-то не стройно, решил проверить. Добро, спасибо.

Comment: @0xdb а если таблица не будет найдена, есть ли специальное исключение для этого? no_data_found не подходит, а others не хочется использовать из-за ширины возможностей.

Comment: Есть конечно - `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'`

Comment: @0xdb - это да, но я про соответствующее исключение. Нагуглилось только no_such_table, но на такое название исключение просит создать объявление (нет, мол, такого исключения).

Comment: Где вы всё ищете? [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609105/dynamic-sql-exception-handling-00942-oracle-pl-sql).

Comment: @0xdb, может оформите в виде ответа с небольшим примером (с обработкой исключения)? Будет хороший пример процедуры для очистки таблиц с обработкой исключений, да и вопрос не будет висеть без ответа...

Comment: @MaxU Набросал заготовку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут поможет динамический SQL - [Native Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01102).

Тест данные:

```
create table tables as 
    select level id, 'table_'||level name
    from dual connect by level <= 4;

select
    'drop table '||name||';'||chr (10)||
    'create table '||name||' as select '||id||' id '|| 
    'from dual connect by level<='||(id*10)||';'
from tables
where id < 4;
```

Выполните результат последнего запроса методом копи+паста, и затем следующее:

```
declare 
    rows number;
    function deleteTableIfExists (name varchar2) return number is
        tableNotExist exception; 
        pragma exception_init (tableNotExist, -942);  
    begin
        execute immediate 'delete from '||name;
        return sql%rowcount;
    exception when tableNotExist then return -1;
    end deleteTableIfExists;
begin
    for r in (select * from tables) loop
        rows := deleteTableIfExists (r.name);
        if rows >= 0 
        then dbms_output.put_line (r.name||' '||rows|| ' rows deleted'); 
        else dbms_output.put_line (r.name||' does not exists');
        end if;
    end loop; 
end;
/

table_1 10 rows deleted
table_2 20 rows deleted
table_3 30 rows deleted
table_4 does not exists

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Обычно подобные функциии собираются в несколько пакетов по категориям один раз для всего проекта, например - `dmlUtils` и `ddlUtils`.