# Динамическое подключение к другой Oracle БД из PL/SQL или SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Надо организовать динамическое подключение к любой из удаленных БД, данные о которых есть в таблице средствами PL/SQL кода.

Можно ли имея таблицу с настроечными параметрами (имя, пароль, TNS), в зависимости от переданного в процедуру параметра (ключа этой таблицы), в коде менять подключение и использовать один и тот же запрос для выборки из одинаковых структур то одной, то другой удаленной БД?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4410488400346721382

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: Нельзя. Подключение к БД (*connect*) невозможно выполнить динамически:

```
exec execute immediate 'connect user/pass@localhost/oradb';
--ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

так, как это недействительное SQL выражение.

---

Для выполнения запросов или хранимых функций на удалённой БД используются линки
 (*[database links](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/distributed-database-concepts.html#GUID-93B235DD-BF66-444D-9F0F-9D4B2F590C41)*). Например, для задачи как в вопросе:

```
create database link loopback1 connect to user identified by pass using 'localhost/pdb1';
create database link loopback2 connect to user identified by pass using 'localhost/pdb1';
create database link loopback3 connect to user identified by pass using 'localhost/pdb1';

set serveroutput on size unlimited
declare
    function printRemoteData (dbLink varchar2) return varchar2 is
        dummy char (1);
    begin
        execute immediate 'select dummy from dual@'||dbLink into dummy;
        -- do something with remote data
        return 'remote connection using @'||dbLink;
    end;
begin
    for r in (
        select * from user_db_links where regexp_like (db_link, 'loopback\d', 'i')) loop
        dbms_output.put_line (printRemoteData (r.db_link));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Вывод:

```
remote connection using @LOOPBACK1
remote connection using @LOOPBACK3
remote connection using @LOOPBACK2
```

Пример решения более реальной задачи см. также по ссылке [спроси Тома](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4410488400346721382) любезно предоставленной @MaxU.

Comment: А может линк создавать автоматически, проверив, существует ли с таким именем? Или совсем не вариант )))

Comment: Можно, примерно как [в этом топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809260/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Comment: Ну да, динамическим SQL. Спасибо.

Comment: Вообще трудно представить бизнес требования, где надо динамически создавать бд линки. Их что, сотни и постоянно обновляётся?

Comment: Нет, есть региональные источники данных с одинаковыми структурами и надо в зависимости от условий обработки на центральном сервере данные брать то из одних источников, то из других. Таких БД - источников около 400. Теоретически могут использоваться все.

Comment: А как источники в таблицу с настроечными параметрами попадают?

Comment: Ну их добавляют, то есть есть таблица со списком всех источников с их параметрами.

Comment: Ну хорошо, только не забудте, что динамические DDL это всегда неявный коммит, т.е. не стоит их выполнять в одной трансакции вместе с изменениями в таблицах.

Comment: Спасибо, учту .